# Wordpress website seems not to be reading my combined js file

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to combine js files to reduce http requests for my wordpress website following this tutorial.

https://speedrak.com/blog/how-to-combine-javascripts-into-1-file/#add-js

I've done the jquery js files first.

I've gone trough all the steps, checked everything twice. My new combined js file is located in the footer (i can see it in the source code). But when i deregister the handles (via functions.php) tied to the js files that i combined in the new file, i lose all function of those  js files (it breaks the accordion  on my website for example). But the code of that accordion jquery js is in the new js file that i created and that file is in the footer and should be read off. But its not happening.

-My new js file contains all the right code from the js files. I've litterally right clicked the javascript line > reveal in sources panel > copied the code + pasted in the my new js file. Exactly in order as they appear in my source code and exactly as stated in the tutorial.

-I know exactly which js file gets deleted from my source code when i deregister the corresponding handle.

Is my new js file too low in the footer maybe? I really hope someone can help me here!

thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at your console. It is definitely NOT reading the js files correctly. For example, it;s looking for "'http://www.yourdomainname.com/includes/js/custom_plugins.021115.js".

Comment: But for my 2 cents, you are wasting time. God files (everything in 1 file) make a website difficult to manage and add to down the line......

Comment: Console shows no errors, only says : JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1. The file name in my footer and in my wordpress directory are exactly the same. 
I've got source code for 8 js files in my new file, but only deregister 4 handles related to 4 js files in that new file. Would this matter?
My wp site would just see the source code for the js file twice, which is better than 0 times and breaking the plugin. not sure if this is it.
Yes i know, but i have 51 http requests and its way too many. First time users are waiting 6 seconds for the page to load. So i have no other option

Comment: I accessed your site again, and the console (Chromium) is still full of 'mixed content' errors, so some js files are not loading.

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
/blog/how-to-combine-javascripts-into-1-file/#add-js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://speedrak.com/blog/how-to-combine-javascripts-into-1-file/#add-js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.yourdomainname.com/includes/js/custom_plugins.021115.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: ...and more, so you need to sort that out before anything else.

Comment: but thats not my wordpress site, thats the tutorial i used.
my wordpress site is: https://tripsitter.store/

In its current state you can see the combined file in the footer and all the present javascripts, without deregistration of certain handles yet. When i deregister these handles: jquery-ui-core, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-tabs and jquery-effects-core. Exactly the 4 associated js files are not requested anymore and are no longer in my source code.

Comment: So i put the code of these js files in my new combined js file, but its not reading my new file correctly hence leaving my accordion broken (those 4 js files are all associated with my accordion). I must be missing something somewhere. 

Really appreciating the help btw!

Comment: Oy, silly me. Sorry about that. Ok, I see what you have done. Not too sure what's happening though, cos when I add a jquery popup at the bottom of your js file (on my localhost) it runs, so the file is loading ok. So too low in the footer? No. All I can suggest it don't use the minified js files, then at least you can add code to debug as you go. (console.log, alerts, etc)

Comment: If you're looking for an easy way to minify and combine html, css, and js there are already free plugins for WP that do this that do very well. Autoptimize is one.

Comment: @JustinR. hey man after trying it manually i gave in and use Autoptimize.
Worked flawlesly. Got it from 53 to 30 requests. In real world performance for first time incognito visitors the load time went from 7 to about 5,5 seconds.